# Units of measure in a 'between' range

Tags: numbers, measuring-units

I've seen lots of similar questions, but none exact to what I'm working with. Example:

Ex. 1: "The result should be between 100 and 300 mm/hr."

Ex. 2: "The result should be between 100 mm/hr and 300 mm/hr."

I know to specify the units if they differ, but they do not in my case. I would presume to do it as in Ex. 1 (only specifying the unit once), but I noticed the journal I am reading does it with both specified, and now I'm oddly curious as to which is correct.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Could depend on your audience: more technical, less repetition.

Comment: Suppose: "I will take two apples or three apples" vs "I will take two or three apples." Is there any doubt in the second one that 'two' is the number of apples? The first isn't *incorrect* but more rigorous (and less natural).

Comment: If you're really constrained by precisionist demands, SI I seem to remember demands mh⁻¹. Some prefer the 0·100–0·300mh⁻¹ format for ranges.

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane; this seems to be a rather straightforward example of conjunction reduction (or whatever you'd like to call it). I don't see why the fact that the optionally omitted element represents units makes any difference.

Comment: I too agree with WeatherVane unless there is a style guide specified which should be adhered to.

Comment: or unless the sentence belongs to a list of similar sentences where min and max use different units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of style, so different sources may give different answers. Indeed, the official NIST guidelines for the use of the SI would require you to use 'between 100 mm/h and 300 mm/h', while the *Chicago Manual of Style* (CMoS) would recommend 'between 100 and 300 mm/h' (arguably; CMoS doesn't treat literally that construction).

Note that both of these authorities say that the abbreviation for 'hour' should be 'h', not 'hr'. Here the unit *hour* is one of 'non-SI units that are accepted for use with the SI'.

Let me also note that SI usage sanctions both 'mm/h' and 'mm · h<sup>-1</sup>' (note the centered dot between 'mm' and 'h<sup>-1</sup>'), as well as the horizontal line,

' mm '
 ——    ;
   h
see [*Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230603132121/https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), p. 13.

The NIST guide in principle allows the multiplication of units to be expressed by a space, as in 'mm h<sup>-1</sup>'. However, it prefers the half-high dot 'because it is less likely to lead to confusion'. Moreover, the Guide notes that it is usually 'imperative' to use either the half-high dot or the space, and *not* simply juxtapose multiplied units. As an example, consider that 'm · s<sup>−1</sup>' is the symbol for the meter per second, while 'ms<sup>−1</sup>' is the symbol for the reciprocal millisecond (10<sup>3</sup> s<sup>−1</sup>).

### SI/NIST

The [SI brochure](https://web.archive.org/web/20230323105746/https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) itself has no recommendation on the subject. However, [NIST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology), one of whose tasks is to interpret or modify the SI for use in the United States, has published [*Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230603132121/https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf), where we find the following (p. 18):

> 225 nm to 2400 nm or (225 to 2400) nm    *but not:*     225 to 2400 nm
> 0 V to 5 V or (0 to 5) V                                      *but not:*    0 − 5 V

For completeness, here is the relevant section in full:

> **7.7 Clarity in writing values of quantities**
>  The value of a quantity is expressed as the product of a number and a unit (see Sec.
> 7.1). Thus, to avoid possible confusion, this Guide takes the position that values of quantities must be written so that it is completely
> clear to which unit symbols the numerical values of the quantities
> belong. Also to avoid possible confusion, this Guide strongly
> recommends that the word “to” be used to indicate a range of values
> for a quantity instead of a range dash (that is, a long hyphen)
> because the dash could be misinterpreted as a minus sign. (The first
> of these recommendations once again recognizes that unit symbols are
> not like ordinary words or abbreviations but are mathematical
> entities—see Sec. 7.2.)
> *Examples:*
>  51 mm × 51 mm × 25 mm                               *but
> not:*    51 × 51 × 25 mm
>  225 nm to 2400 nm or
> (225 to 2400) nm   *but
> not:*    225 to 2400 nm
>  0 °C to 100 °C or (0
> to 100)
> °C                      *but
> not:*    0 °C − 100 °C
>  0 V to 5 V or (0 to 5)
> V                                    *but
> not:*    0 − 5 V
>  (8.2, 9.0, 9.5, 9.8, 10.0)
> GHz                         *but
> not:*    8.2, 9.0, 9.5, 9.8, 10.0 GHz
> 63.2 m ± 0.1 m or (63.2 ± 0.1) m                  *but
> not:*    63.2 ± 0.1 m or 63.2 m ± 0.1
>  129 s −
> 3 s = 126 s or (129 − 3) s = 126 s     *but
> not:*    129 − 3 s = 126 s

### CMoS

To understand the CMoS recommendation, it will be helpful to first note the following (from CMoS):

> **10.58: SI units and abbreviations—spacing**
> …
>  In SI usage as in general usage, a space usually appears between the numeral and any
> abbreviation or symbol. Contrary to general usage, however, SI usage
> also stipulates a space before a percentage sign (%) or before a
> degree symbol used for temperature (compare the advice in the
> introduction to the table at 10.49). In expressions of degrees,
> minutes, and seconds, SI usage shows (but does not stipulate) a space
> between quantities. Many publications do not observe these exceptions,
> and Chicago does not require them in its publications.
> *SI style*         *Chicago
> style*
>  22
> °C                22°C
> 22° 14′ 33″     22°14′33″
> 0.5 %               0.5%
> (see also 9.18)

Now comes the actual recommendation that interests us:

> **9.17: Units for repeated quantities**
>  For expressions including two or more quantities, the abbreviation or symbol is
> repeated if it is closed up to the number but not if it is separated.
> See also 10.49. For the use of spaces with SI units and abbreviations
> or symbols, see 10.58.
>  35%–50%
>  3°C–7°C
>  6¾″ × 9″
>  2
> × 5 cm

Comment: Very thorough, and seems to depend on authority rather than grammatical analysis.  I also recommend the clarity and conciseness of @weathervane’s comment.